# How can I create a "new Outlook note" quick launch toolbar shortcut?

Tags: windows-vista, microsoft-outlook-2007

I would like to have an "Outlook note" shortcut on my Windows Vista quick launch toolbar. When clicked, it should open up a new note that will be saved in Outlook, like the "new note" command in Outlook. I only know how to make a similar shortcut that is **not** bound to Outlook and doesn't show up as a new note within Outlook. I tried clicking and dragging and pasting without success. I need this, so that my users can rapidly type notes without having to open Outlook first. How can I create such a shortcut?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make a new shortcut pointing to:

`"C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\Office12\OUTLOOK.EXE" /c ipm.stickynote`

...and drag it to the quicklaunch bar.

You'll have to change the path if you are using Vista x64 with Office x86.

[More command line arguments here.](http://www.howto-outlook.com/howto/commandlineswitches.htm)

Comment: the suffix fdoesnt work "/c ipm.stickynote" . please advise

Comment: @Nathaniel_613: Are you sure you have the path right?  Have you used quotes around the executable path, but not the switch and argument?  I tested it with Outlook 2010 (with a different path) and it works fine, and the link I gave says that there is nothing different with 2007.

Comment: @Nathaniel_613: I am not sure how you are making the shortcut, but you may have to make sure that the `Start In` field has the path for Outlook, without the executable.  eg. `"C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\Office12\"`

Comment: Thanks for this - however, please bear in mind that for Office 2010 you need to change the path to Office14 rather than Office12 or it will not find outlook.exe!